# What asp.net portal software should I use for my personal site?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, app-store, portal, community-server

I want to set up my personal programming-oriented website.   I'm currently running a very old version of CommunityServer, but I'd like to move on to something else.    My host is WINS-based (Windows, IIS, .NET, SQL Server).

I need blogging, forums, and an appstore with google checkout or paypal integration.   I've looked around and found a couple asp.net portals (a la DotNetNuke, CommunityServer) but neither solution seems to easily fit the bill, although I'm sure I could make them work with a lot of elbowgrease.

So i'm throwing this question out to the community to see if there's any good free/cheap, and easy solutions out there.

Criteria:

- Free / cheap
- Blogging, static pages, comments, pingback / tracking, etc
- Storefront / payment processing integration (as a feature or add-in module preferably)
- File hosting (nothing major)
- Forums, subforums
- User self-registration, captcha & other anti-spam measures

UPDATE 1

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646538/cms-for-a-personal-website-asp-net-c) but there's nothing there about storefront/payment system integration.

UPDATE 2

Maybe i'm coming at this in the wrong direction.   Is there a .NET blogging software that has file hosting & forums (either integrated or as a plugin)?

The more I think about the storefront, the more I think i'll just have to roll my own anyway.

Answer (score 2):

About a year ago when I was looking into open source ASP.NET content management apps, I found that DotNetNuke was one of the better solutions. I know there are a lot of 3rd party modules for DNN available from places like [Snowcovered.com](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/), so I'm willing to bet you can find a storefront/ecommerce module that will meet your needs. Most of the modules are pretty cheap, < $100.

Another option that I have used in the past is [TheBeerHouse](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/the-beer-house/) starter site, straight from www.asp.net. The site includes a storefront, and some more stuff like forums, content rating, and self registration.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Sueetie](http://sueetie.com/wiki/Default.aspx) is looking pretty good for this. You'd need a similar amount of elbowgrease to get it as you want though...

Comment: Thanks, Sueetie looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can look also at [Rainbow portal](http://www.rainbowportal.org/)

It's open source, ASP.NET, C#.

Update: I used this portal in 2003, in this time it was more advanced than DNN, now I looked at their site, it looks like that they stopped development, last version for .NET 2 ans still alpha.

There is also [ASP.NET Portal Starter Kit](http://www.codeplex.com/ASPNETPortal), which is development of IBuySpy portal, but I think that DNN has more features.

Comment: Yep, Rainbow Portal is pretty well dead at this point. I wouldn't recommend using it as you will not have any community to leverage.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I can't comment on the other answers.

If you liked Community Server before Telligent started turning on the lower end users then you'll probably like Sueetie. From what I understand it was set up by former users of Community Server when Telligent started taking away all the reasonably priced licenses that community users used to run their social networking websites. Dave Burke who is mentioned on the home page of Sueetie was once upon a time a kind of MVP for Community Server, contributing massively in the Community Server forums, he started Sueetie